# Execution failed for task :app:processDebugResources Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-state

Alright, After running someone else's Flutter code, I got the following error and couldn't and stopped the execution of the task.
This was the error code:

[image: ERROR]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my senior dev told me to do the following.

- go to `androidmanifest` file by android -> app -> src -> main
- now delete this line `android:userCleartextTraffic`